# React - Show one result for results that have a value greater than n

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array and I would like to display one item from the array at random as long as the item has a `value` greater than or equal to `3`. So far I am able to select one of them items at random but I am not sure how to only select an item with a value greater than or equal to 3.

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = [
    {
      "name": "lorem",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "ipsum",
      "value": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "dolor",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "sit",
      "value": 2
    }
  ];
  const rand = arr.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).find(() => true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {rand &&
        <div>{rand.name}</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: that `sort` function is necessary? you should pick from only a sorted array?

Comment: I would just like to select one item at random from the array where `value` is greater than or equal to `3`. The sort function is just what I found on SO for selecting an item at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm how about trying this...

```
const arr = ['your data']; 
// your array here
const newarr = arr.filter(item=>item.value>3) 
// fetch items >3 from array into new array
const randItem = newarr[Math.floor(Math.random() * newarr.length)]
//get any random item from the array
```

Comment: please note if the domain is small i.e if the newarr size is small the random function would have a tendency to pick the same element multiple times before moving on to the other elements. For uniqueness, you can save the value returned in a variable and call the random function repeatedly until you get a new value.